# Loading multi versioned Web Component dependencies with SystemJS / JSPM?

Tags: ecmascript-6, polymer-1.0, web-component, systemjs, jspm

Just a disclaimer - this is a hypothetical scenario as I'm trying to figure out the best way to handle web component direct and transitive dependencies using something like [JSPM](http://jspm.io/) and [SystemJS](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs).

### Scenario 1

Suppose I have 2 web components - `component-a` and `component-b`.  One is built with `momentjs@1.2.4` and another is built with `momentjs@1.6.4`.

Each component author listed `Polymer` as a peer dependency and `momentjs` as a direct dependency in their package.json file like this:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "moment.js": ">= 1.0.1 <= 1.8.0"
  }   
  "peerDependencies": {
    "Polymer.js": "0.5.0^",
  }
```

So in this case when the developer declares the package.json dependencies on both of these components the package manager could figure out the best version of `moment.js` to install and make it available.  Lets assume that's version `1.8.0`.

Great - just one version of `moment.js` to deal with for both components.  Now how do the components load / inject the dependency?  Does [JSPM](http://jspm.io/) and [SystemJS](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs) currently have the ability to support this?

For example in this article [Taming Polymer with SystemJS and Typescript](http://blog.charto.net/typescript/Taming-Polymer-with-SystemJS-and-TypeScript-part-1/) the author performs imports that delegate to SystemJS like this:

```
 import 'elements/app-frontend';
```

So I suppose momentjs would follow a similar approach and import like this (Within the typescript files of `component-a` and `component-b`:

```
 import 'js/momentjs';
```

In the above case the `momentjs` dependency does not know what version will be fetched since the import declaration is unaware of the version (since it written at design time).

Later on when the component is used in and component is used in an application JSPM figures out the best for the `momentjs` depedency to install.

In this case lets assume that it install it in a layout like this:

```
`jspm_packages/momentjs/momentjs@1.8.0`
```

So how does JSPM become aware the import statement `import 'js/momentjs'` translates to the import of `jspm_packages/momentjs/momentjs@1.8.0`?

In this case it's fairly trivial, but it get more tricky in scenario 2 below ... I think.

### Scenario 2

Same as scenario one except the version requirements on `momentjs` are mutually exclusive.  For example `component-a` requires version `1.2.4` and `component-b` requires version `2.4.4`.

So both components perform the import like this:

```
 import 'js/momentjs';
```

But `jspm_packages` installs both versions like this:

```
`jspm_packages/momentjs/momentjs@1.4.4`
`jspm_packages/momentjs/momentjs@2.4.4`
```

So now how does SystemJS know to that `component-a` needs version `1.4.4` and `component-b` needs version `2.4.4`?

To summarize:
1) Is JSPM ok with having multiple versions of the same dependency?

According to this article [Introduction to the Jspm package manager and the SystemJs module loader](http://blog.angular-university.io/introduction-to-es6-modularity-the-jspm-package-manager-and-the-systemjs-loader/) and an answer from [guybeford](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/issues/1426) it does, but how then does each component get the right version?

2) Does SystemJS / JSPM have a way of configuring version meta data for each component?

3) Does SystemJS have a way of understanding and injecting the right version of a dependency into the web component?

TIA,
Ole

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you using ES6 `import` syntax?

Comment: Also, regarding 2), what kind of meta data do you have in mind?

Comment: Hi - I updated the question to hopefully make it clearer - Lets assume ES6 `import` syntax.  The meta data would be the meta data that SystemJS would need in order to inject the right version of momentjs into the corresponding component based on the package.json dependency declaration.  So the metadata is essentially the dependency name and version requirement from package.json when the version is fixed.  When it's not fixed then JSPM would have provide the meta data after it has performed the dependency resolution step.

Comment: ES6 imports are definitely a better choice. Without them I don't think you will be able to bundle effectively

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Also what happens if the component requires several other modules, like CSS etc?

I'm not sure what you mean. You can import multiple modules and other contents (likely via plugins) usting SystemJS.

> 1) Is JSPM ok with having multiple versions of the same dependency?

I think you partially answered this question. JSPM will always select and install only one version for each component, which best matches the requirements from other components. If there is a conflict, JSPM will ask to choose manually.

> So how does JSPM become aware the import statement import 'js/momentjs' translates to the import of jspm_packages/momentjs/momentjs@1.8.0?

The config.js file assigns import names (not sure the nomenclature) for installed packages. It is actually possible to change those names using `jspm install x=npm:package` syntax. This will result in config like

```
"x": "npm:package@1.2.3"
```

You can then both `import x` and `import npm:package@1.2.3`.

> 2) Does SystemJS / JSPM have a way of configuring version meta data for each component?

I think that the structure of config.js has all you need. It contains dependencies with their versions.

```
"component-a": {
  "momentjs": "momentjs@1.2.4"
},
"component-b": {
  "momentjs": "momentjs@1.6.4"
}
```

> 3) Does SystemJS have a way of understanding and injecting the right version of a dependency into the web component?

I would expect SystemJS to use this information to import the correct version when either `component-a` or `component-b` is requested.

I am not sure though how to have JSPM install packages this way, retaining multiple versions of a package. I think it deserves a separate, specialized question.

Comment: OK - Cool the other modules part should be pretty trivial - thanks.  I was looking at the Polymer.import statements which I think assumes that all other modules are lumped together into a single html import.  Guy Bedford and the documentation does say that JSPM supports multi version depedencies ... just not clear on how.  I'm wondering how SystemJS will figure out that component-a needs version 1.4.4 and comopnent-b needs version 2.4.4 of the same dependency.

Comment: I updated my answer. I haven't tried, please see if it works for you.

Comment: And regarding `Polymer.import` it doesn't do much. It basically just inserts a `<link rel="import>` into the `<head>`. It doesn't care whether modules are bundled or not. Definitely not an alternative to `import 'x'`